# javamail connect to imap over ssl to read mails

Tags: ssl, imap, jakarta-mail

I want to read emails from exchange server over IMAP SSL with JavaMail API. I am using the following piece of code.

> Properties props =System.getProperties();
>
> props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol","imaps");
>
> Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
>
> Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
>
> store.connect("server hostname","username","password");

But I am unable to establish a connection. All I get is following error.

> javax.mail.MessagingException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
> PKIX path validation failed:
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
> timestamp check failed;   nested
> exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
> PKIX path validation failed:
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
> timestamp check failed  at
> com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:618)
> at
> javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
> at
> javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
> at

I am not sure if there are any pre-requisite steps to be followed for establishing a connection.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to which mail server u r trying to connect?? replace IMAPS with IMAP and try it.

If you really need to use IMAPS try this

http://blogs.oracle.com/andreas/entry/no_more_unable_to_find

Comment: The link you are referring to is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

Your particular error seems to indicate that your current SSL certificate is expired.

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed

You either need to renew your SSL certificate or configure your mail server to point to the correct one.